# Error con dropdownlist :No puede haber varios elementos seleccionados en DropDownList

Tags: asp.net

Este error me acaba de surgir en mi GridView porque tengo 6 dropdownlist dentro del GridView en EditItemTemplate, y cuando doy click en Editar, pasa este error:

> System.Web.HttpException: No puede haber varios elementos
>   seleccionados en DropDownList.

Este es mi Code-Behind:

```
 Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow AndAlso GridView1.EditIndex = e.Row.RowIndex Then
        Dim ddlParIDF As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddlParIDF"), DropDownList)
        Dim ddlFilaIDF As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddlFilaIDF"), DropDownList)
        Dim ddlTabIDF As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddlTabIDF"), DropDownList)
        ddlParIDF.Items.FindByValue(TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblParIDF"), Label).Text).Selected = True
        ddlFilaIDF.Items.FindByValue(TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblFilaIDF"), Label).Text).Selected = True
        ddlTabIDF.Items.FindByValue(TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblTabIDF"), Label).Text).Selected = True

        Dim ddlFilaMDF As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddlFilaMDF"), DropDownList)
        Dim ddlTabMDF As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddlTabMDF"), DropDownList)
        Dim ddlParMDF As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddlParMDF"), DropDownList)
        ddlFilaMDF.Items.FindByValue(TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblFilaMDF"), Label).Text).Selected = True
        ddlTabIDF.Items.FindByValue(TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblTabMDF"), Label).Text).Selected = True
        ddlParMDF.Items.FindByValue(TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblParMDF"), Label).Text).Selected = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Utilizo un Label dentro de EditItemTemplate junto al DropDownList para guardar el último valor seleccionado del dropdownlist, pero me doy cuenta que si quito los ".Selected = True" de dos o más Label, este error ya no pasa, pero la desventaja es que no me guardará el último valor escogido del DropDownList.

Para el llenado de los DropDownList uso los ListItems dentro del gridview.

O si alguien sabe que exista otra manera de mantener el valor seleccionado, si pudiera ayudarme también.

Gracias a todos!

Answer (score 1):

En el segundo bloque estas usando **ddlTabIDF** o sea en este:

```
ddlFilaMDF.Items.FindByValue(TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblFilaMDF"), Label).Text).Selected = True
ddlTabIDF.Items.FindByValue(TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblTabMDF"), Label).Text).Selected = True
ddlParMDF.Items.FindByValue(TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblParMDF"), Label).Text).Selected = True
```

cuando deberia ser **ddlTabMDF**